# PUT method. ORM Symfony 4. Неизвесто почему возникает ошибка. Не вижу где происходит вызов несуществуещего класса

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, orm

Пытаюсь обновить данные в базе. Но в процессе получаю ошибку `Class App\Entity\User does not exist`

Но нигде этого `User` я на прямую не вызываю, и не понимаю почему вызов происходит. Сам метод:

```
public function updateAction(Request $request) : Response
{

try {
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = $em->getRepository(UserEntity::class)->find($data['id']);
    if (!$user) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
           'No user found for id '.$data['id']
        );
    }

    $user->setPassword($data['password']);
    $user->setPassword($data['email']);
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
    return new JsonResponse(['User update is successfully' => $data['id']], 201);

    var_dump($data);

  } catch (Exception $e) {
    return $this->fail($e);
  }
}
```

подключения:

```
namespace App\Portmone\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\Exception;
use App\Portmone\Entity\UserEntity;
```

В чём причина? Спасибо!

UPD

брейкпоинтами дохожу до места :

`$user = $em->getRepository(UserEntity::class)->find($data['id']);`

и уже здесь уже получаю данную ошибку

`UserEntity`

```
namespace App\Portmone\Entity;

use App\Portmone\Exception\InvalidSignUpException;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

 /**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
 class UserEntity
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 */
private $email;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getPassword(): ?string
{
    return $this->password;
}

public function setPassword(string $password): self
{
    $passwordSize = strlen($password);
    if($passwordSize < 5 || $passwordSize > 32){
        throw new InvalidSignUpException();
    }

    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

public function getEmail(): ?string
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function setEmail(string $email): self
{
    $emailSize = strlen($email);
    if($emailSize < 5 || $emailSize > 32){
        throw new InvalidSignUpException();
    }
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}
```

}

Comment: Обычно в сообщениях указывается строка в коде где происходит ошибка.

Comment: Также не знаю почему (может это глючит парсер) но переменная `$user` у вас в коде выделяется по разному. Копните в эту сторону, может какие-то невыводимые символы затесались.

Comment: @u_mulder, спасибо, попробую поискать в этом направлении

Comment: А можете кинуть содержимое UserEntity?

Comment: И еще вариант. Если вы создали сначала User, а потом переименовали в UserEntity, то старый класс мог закешироваться. Сделайте `console cache:clear`

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, добавил Entity. При попытк очистить кэш получил проблему с `autoload` - ищет файлы которые я удалил. Пока что решаю этот вопрос

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `$em->getRepository(UserEntity::class)->find($data['id']);` сделать `$em->find(UserEntity::class, $data['id']);`

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, господи, да Вы наверняка волшебник. Да, это помогло. Спсибо! Но в чём же дело? Добавте как ответ)

Comment: Это не ответ. Смотрите ошибку в репозитории

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, почему не ответ? Я добавил эту строчку так же в методы `delete` и `read` - кругом заработало. База адекватно реагирует на команды

Comment: Это просто find без использования репозитория. Ошибка вываливается при getRepository. Значит в классе репозитория ошибка, которая когда-нибудь вылезет

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, а, вот как. Ну ,во всяком случае - спасибо. Я об этом моменте хотя бы вкурсе буду